# CSS styled DropDownList at asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-ui

Does anyone have a better styled DropDownList or ready css file for the asp:DropDownList?
I could not find something finished at www?!

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="50px">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I could imagine something like [jQuery UI style](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

Thanks for your constructive answers!

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery UI styles, which are available for free?

Comment: I found only this: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: @OndrejJanacek how to use or combine ui styles? It's not finished to use the class="ui-widget"

Comment: @SigiAnonym Use the Theme Roller on their website so you style a dropdownlist as you wish, then download your custom style and go through css files where you find all you need.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I will try it... I hoped someone has an finish solution.

Comment: @SigiAnonym Someone sure has, but nobody gives up their content so easily. It costs time to create a good looking style. If you don't mind using jQuery UI in your web application, just go with it and you will have cool stiles available.

Comment: Take a look into this : http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [this](http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3) in my project look's good.

Comment: @Sigi Anonym - Let me know if this works for you, will be glad. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/era/86PJ2/2/)

```
 .dropdown1 {    
    background: url(http://maxgxl.com/max4u/images/selectArrowDown.png) no-repeat 95% center;
    width:150px;
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    border-radius:5px;
}
.dropdown1 select {
    border:0px; 
    width:168px; 
    background:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The link you have shared here seems to be a comboBox. If you want to design your dropdownlist control then you can have your own styles as well.

Think of the same link that you have given here. It contains a textbox having a button whose background image is a small triangle that seems to be a dropdownlist, and a simple div/list control(ul-li) that contains all the items that are populated below the dropdown list.

Now you need to decide what you need to have in your design. based upon your requirement you can customize your dropdownlist here.

See this is just a way how you can create your customized dropdownlist of your own style. If you go for the jquery dropdownlist then you can have the same look and feel that you can have designed of your own. So you decide the things you want to have with your dropdownlist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.search_categories .select{

  background: transparent;

  line-height: 1;

  border: 0;

  padding: 0;

  border-radius: 0;

  width: 120%;

  position: relative;

  z-index: 10;

  font-size: 1em;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind explaining your solution?

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. Please update your answer to explain how this improves on the other accepted and upvoted answers this question already has. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).